# List of JSON items in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio-2.1

I have this json:

```
{
"sid": "BiQo7DA4lMoRkeGN8mdfBXackyBarCSSauQtNRRKOmcfo2Ah0XCjaI1yevEoxWa09TkTOYrwGixRMvBr15h1d2",
"submissions": [{
    "submission_id": "1104764"
}, {
    "submission_id": "1104765"
}]
}
```

How can I in AndroidStudio get a list of items by submission_id?(there is always 30 items in "submissions")

Thanks

UPDATED

---

I'm trying with this code but show exception.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject subm = jObject.getJSONObject("submissions");
                        JSONObject jObj = subm.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
                        testdata = testdata + " " + jObject.getString("submission_id");
                        //
                    }
```

I basically want to get all the elements inside the "submissions"...
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? This is a JSONArray, try something, post it here if have trouble.

Comment: Tip: Android studio has nothing to do with your question

Comment: Edited, added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
if (!jObject.isNull("submissions")) {
    JSONArray submissions = jObject.getJSONArray("submissions");

    for(int i = 0; i < submissions.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject submission = submissions.getJSONObject(i);
        String submissionId = submission.getString("submission_id");
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives error in JSONArray submissions = jObject.getJSONArray("submissions");

Say no value for submissions....

I did "Log.d("Test", jObject.getString("submissions"));"
And it gave me a list like...

[{"submission_id":"1105211"}, {....}]

I thnk the problem is with "[]"

Comment: Can you make one more test: **String submissionsType = jObject.get("submissions").getClass().getSimpleName();** What is a value of **submissionsType**?

Comment: When you receive an exception **No value for..** it means that jObject doesn't have the requested field. When a field cannot be converted to JSONArray there is a different exception with a message: Value cannot be converted to JSONArray.

Comment: It send back "JSONArray"

Comment: @James - I modified a little bit my code, added check for submissions existance. However if you receive "JSONArray", the previous version should also work.

Answer (score 1):

Path : POJO classes -> GSON -> list

You can use [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to read JSON into Java objects.

POJO

```
   public class Submission
    {
        public String submission_id;

        public Submission(String submission_id)
        {
           this.submission_id = submission_id;
        }
    }

    public class SubmissionObject
    {
        public String sid;
        public List<Submission> submissions;

        public SubmissionObject(String sid,List<Submission> submissions)
        {
           this.sid = sid;
           this.submissions = submissions;
        }
    }
```

POJOs are ready. Let's parse the JSON response by using GSON.

```
     public List<Submission> submissions = new ArrayList<>();//your list holds the all submissions.

     Gson gson = new Gson();// initialize GSON parser
     SubmissionObject object = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse.toString(), SubmissionObject.class); //get the object
     submissions = object.submissions; // set list
```